# Is it necessary placing exit/cancel/close button if there are 'x' (close button) at the pop up window

Tags: forms, close

My dekstop application use a lot of .showdialog to open new form. Then it's necessary placing some method for the user who want close the popup form. I already using 'x' (close form, near minimize and maximize) in case user need to close the form.

Do i **need** adding exit/cancel/close in all popup form too ?

For example :

[image: Include]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** You do need a matching <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button to go with <kbd>Save</kbd>. If you don't, it may not be obvious how to close the dialog except via <kbd>Save</kbd>:

[image: Dialog with only Save button]

This is particularly the case where the other buttons such as the <kbd>X</kbd> are only coloured on hover — as appears to be the case here. It may be less important if the <kbd>X</kbd> is always red. However, **you should also consider accessibility.** A screen-reading application won't necessarily identify a way to close the dialog via system buttons, and if there is no <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button it may not react to the keyboard's <kbd>Esc</kbd> either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the major influencers today actually agree on *which buttons to show*, but disagree on whether or not to show the *'X to close'* button to the top.

According to [Microsoft MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx), modal dialogs in Windows have both an X to close as well as buttons that perform the action and then close.

But this has changed in both [Apple latest iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Modal.html) and [Google material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content). Both have dropped the X to close in modal dialogs, leaving just the buttons.

Comment: The question is about showing the button in the dialog, not if you should show the corner "x" button. So it does not depend on who you ask - you always show the dialog button. The guidelines you point to stress exactly that.

Comment: Agreed. I've removed that line from the answer.